# Match several items within a field

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to create an efficient search using linq

Users input their search keywords (or first few characters) and I parse that into an array.

For the first part, I want to find the instances of the search field where all of the words are found. (Later, I search for any, but that part is working)

```
string[] arSearchString = searchString.Split(',', ' ', ';');
var codes = from c in CodeList
            where arSearchString.All(val => c.Description.StartsWith(val) || 
                                            c.Description.Contains(" " + val))
            select c;
```

This returns nothing.

What I want to happen is to return items in which all words in the array are found within the description field
For example, if they typed "cat dog", I should get back things like:

```
"A Cat and a Dog"
"Dogs and Cats"
"Catatonic Dogma"
```

But not items that only match only one of the keys (e.g., "My Life as a Dog")

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong or offer a solution?

Answer (score 5):

**Make sure you take casing into account**. Use `ToUpper` as that's optimised for string comparisons. **EDIT: I've gone for `ToUpperInvariant` to be culture-safe :)**

Try this:

```
string[] arSearchString = searchString.Split(',', ' ', ';');
var codes = from c in CodeList
        where arSearchString.All(val => c.Description.ToUpperInvariant().StartsWith(val.ToUpperInvariant()) || 
                                 c.Description.ToUpperInvariant().Contains(" " + val.ToUpperInvariant()))
        select c;
```

**But I'm really tempted to convert that to chaining, as it's a bit messy**. I prefer this, but you can choose either:

```
string[] arSearchString = searchString.Split(',', ' ', ';');
var codes = CodeList
    .Where(c => arSearchString
        .All(val => c.Description.ToUpperInvariant().StartsWith(val.ToUpperInvariant()) 
            || c.Description.ToUpperInvariant().Contains(" " + val.ToUpperInvariant())))
```

Comment: I do the Any in another search if the first one returns nothing. Pretty much like you have it.  But I want to return only those records where the description field has all of those words.

Comment: @Adam Updated. Make sure you're correctly casing. As searching for `cat dog` in your code **won't** match `Cat Dog` because of the capitals.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where's the source for this? _Use ToUpper as that's optimised for string comparisons_

Comment: @AustinSalonen Ah, comes from good old FxCop (that's where I got it): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386042.aspx

Comment: @Adam No problems glad I could help. If this was the correct answer, please click the tick next to it. Welcome to SO :)

Answer (score 1):

The query is going to be case sensitive, so, in your example, you wouldn't get any results simply because you search for `cat` but that doesn't match `Cat`. Try converting both the search string and the comparison to `.ToUpper()` or `.ToLower()`